# Converting multiple iff V1 Function to V5 (Tradingview - Pine Script)

Tags: pine-script, trading, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v4

I tried to convert pine v1 iff function to v3 (and afterwards convert it automatically to V5) but I kept getting this error:

> extraneous input 'if' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

This is the V1 code

```
bcolor = iff( val > 0, 
            iff( val > nz(val[1]), lime, green),
            iff( val < nz(val[1]), red, maroon))
```

This is what I tried to convert it to V3

```
bcolor = if (val > 0) and (val > nz(val[1]))
    lime
else if
    (val < 0) and (val > nz(val[1]))
    green
else if
    (val > 0) and (val < nz(val[1]))
    red
else
    maroon
```

Does this even make sense in a logical way? Im not quite sure if I did it correctly so that the result is the same like in the iff function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iff()` designed this way:

```
iff(condition, result1, result2)
```

If `condition` is `true`, it will return `result1`. Else, it will return `result2`.

The correct way of converting that block would be:

```
bcolor = if (val > 0)
    if (val > nz(val[1]))
        lime
    else
        green
else
    if (val < nz(val[1]))
        red
    else
        maroon
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thank you very much - I appreciate your help. And thanks for pushing me to show some effort. It helped to understand things better!